# regex — string between multiple pattern

Tags: regex

I need to get multiple matches between multiple possible pattern

This is raw data example:

> DC00-01-14 blabla blabla MB00-07-10 blublu CN03 bli BLI2454 bli bli CN02
>   bloblo bloblo bloblo SYSA bloublou bloublou bloublou CN06 blaiblai
>   blaiblai blaiblai METR blybly blybly blybly ppag blubliblouBFD 454

and the regex should match like this:

> DC00-01-14 blabla blabla
>   MB00-07-10 blublu
>   CN03 bli BLI2454 bli bli
>   CN02 bloblo bloblo bloblo
>   SYSA bloublou bloublou bloublou
>   CN06 blaiblai blaiblai blaiblai
>   METR blybly blybly blybly
>   ppag blubliblouBFD 454

With this expression, I am able to detect the keys:

```
((DC\d{2}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2})|(MB\d{2}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2})|(CN0\d{1})|(SYSA)|(ppag)|(METR))
```

but I need to get the string in between with the first key (without the second key) like in my result example.

What should I do?

https://regex101.com/r/vyi864/1

Comment: When asking about regular expressions, it is a good idea to specify which host language you're working with.  The answer can vary — there are lots of different species of regular expression, and what works in Perl or Python may not work in Java or JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

What I did is placed your regexp in the beggining so it will match once and used a pattern similar to(?:(?!REGEXP).)* which would match till the REGEXP is found but does not include the regexp. put your regexp for the token in place of REGEXP.

> ((DC\d{2}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2})|(MB\d{2}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2})|(CN0\d{1})|(SYSA)|(ppag)|(METR))(?:(?!(((DC\d{2}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2})|(MB\d{2}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2})|(CN0\d{1})|(SYSA)|(ppag)|(METR)))).)*

For Ignoring New Line,
Try something like this (?:\s*(?!REGEXP).)* instead of (?:(?!REGEXP).)* .
The \s* would match newline if present.

(((DC|MB)\d{2}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2})|(CN0\d{1})|(SYSA)|(ppag)|(METR))(?:\s*(?!((((DC|MB)\d{2}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2})|(CN0\d{1})|(SYSA)|(ppag)|(METR)))).)*

Hope this will help.

You can see in the right hand that the full match is in the desired way.
[image]

Comment: this is great seems to be perfect but now if i don t want to stop at new line ?

Comment: If you're using Java, you can use DOTALL and MULTILINE flags when compiling a regular expression. You can find similar flags in other languages too.

Comment: @byron I have added the RegExp which does not stop at new line. Hope it solves your problem.  https://regex101.com/r/vyi864/3